# How to get MagicMock to return multiple values

Tags: python, mocking, magicmock

I'm trying to mock a library (`matplotlib` for what it's worth), and am hitting an issue where it fails when the mock is called expecting a tuple returned. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:15) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin

>>> import mock
>>> foo = mock.MagicMock()
>>> a, b = foo()
```

This is the error message received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
>>>
```

Comment: it's not a duplicate. The other one wants to change the return value between calls to the function. This one wants to return multiple MagicMocks

Answer (score 2):

*(For those who got here curious about one mock returning different distinct values, see my use of `side_effect` at the end of my answer below.)*

I'll start with the first statement in your question:

> I'm trying to mock a library (`matplotlib` for what it's worth)

If you are able to mock this library properly, you shouldn't have to worry about the behavior of any the subfunctions - as they will all be mocked and you can determine how the mocked functions should behave.  How I have achieved similar behavior is by using `patch` - specifically, `patch.object` should help:

```
import mock

mock_matplotlib = mock.MagicMock()
mock_matplotlib.return_value = whatever_mock_behavior_you_want

with mock.patch.object(my_app, "matplotlib", mock_matplotlib):
    # Call the function you are testing which uses matplotlib
```

You now have the freedom to substitute whatever you'd like in for `mock_matplotlib` so that it behaves in the way you seek...  (i.e. `mock_matplotlib.return_value = mock_tuple`) Let's explore some of those possibilities.

You are correct when [you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172582/how-to-get-magicmock-to-return-multiple-values#comment97086912_55172697) that `MagicMock` always returns a `MagicMock` for anything called on it - however, with that statement of `a, b = foo()`, Python is expecting to find a tuple and the error is triggering before the `MagicMock` can create the default single `MagicMock` return value, so the error says that it finds `0` values to work with.

Your solution of creating a tuple of `MagicMock`s could work a number of different ways - it is not clear from your question whether assigning values with `a, b =` is more important to you or not.  If it is then you could do this:

```
import mock
foo = mock.MagicMock()
a, b = (mock.MagicMock(), mock.MagicMock())
```

or this:

```
a, b = (foo(), foo())
```

Or, if you are more interested in having one function call fill those values for you, [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172697/5365001), you could assign a `return_value` like this:

```
foo = mock.MagicMock()
foo.return_value = (mock.MagicMock(), mock.MagicMock())
a, b = foo()
```

or even like this:

```
foo = mock.MagicMock(return_value=(mock.MagicMock(), mock.MagicMock()))
a, b = foo()
```

For those who are curious about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172582/how-to-get-magicmock-to-return-multiple-values#comment98257173_55172582), the OP is correct that this is different from returning a different value each time the `MagicMock` is called.  That would use the `side_effect` option - however, even that could be used to achieve the OP's goal - albeit in a roundabout way:

```
mock_1 = mock.MagicMock()
mock_2 = mock.MagicMock()
foo = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=[mock_1, mock_2])

a, b = (foo(), foo())
```

In that last example, `mock_1` is assigned to `a`, and `mock_2` is assigned to `b`.

Comment: i guess the issue i'm hitting is that the matplotlib API is pretty complicated, so I don't want to have to write special cases every time a function might return a tuple.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus - is the line `a, b = ...` in your actual code being tested?  I added a bit to the front of my answer about mocking the whole `matplotlib` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `return_value` attribute of the `MagicMock` object with a tuple of your choice:

```
import mock
foo = mock.MagicMock()
foo.return_value = 1, 2
a, b = foo()
assert a == 1
assert b == 2
```

Comment: hmm. that's do-able but non-ideal. usually when i use `MagicMock` it always returns a `MagicMock` for anything called on it. so now what i'd do is `foo.return_value = (mock.MagicMock, mock.MagicMock)` (or my my specific case `matplotlib.plt.subplots.return_value = (mock.MagicMock, mock.MagicMock)`