# How to test out if a object's method is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

Hi I am trying to test to see if a method in object A calls another object, object B's, methods. I already have separate tests which tests B's functionality so my goal is just to see if B's method has been called. I am trying to use mocks to create a mock object B, following a method similar to [this](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-unit-test-functions-without-return-statements-in-python/), but keep getting the following error: `AssertionError: Expected 'process' to have been called once. Called 0 times.` Am I doing the mock wrong?

From my understanding, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975146/patch-assertionerror-expected-to-have-been-called-once-called-0-times) suggested to access the field in sut and set it to a mock, but due to how my code is setup I can not access the other objects.

**Example code:**

```py
# object B
from abc import ABCMeta


class B(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def process(self):
        print('I am B')
```

```py
# object C
from abc import ABCMeta


class C(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def process(self):
        print('I am C')
```

```py
# object A
from abc import ABCMeta

from b import B
from c import C


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__known_auto_processes = {}
        self.__inti_know_processes()

    def process(self, arg):
        try:
            self.__known_auto_processes[arg].process()
        except KeyError as error:
            print(f'Invalid arg option {error.args}.')

    def __inti_know_processes(self):
        self.__known_auto_processes['B'] = B()
        self.__known_auto_processes['C'] = C()
```

**Example Test:**

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from a import A


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("b.B")
    def test_b_call(self, mock_b):
        a = A()
        a.process('B')
        mock_b.process.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: You patch where things are _used_, not where they're _defined_ - this is called out _specifically_ [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Answer (score 1):

These posts helped me [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172582/how-to-get-magicmock-to-return-multiple-values) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512708/how-to-properly-mock-private-members-of-a-class?newreg=e951f57e759d4a14b190cda019f4f6af). Something like this should work. I think what this does is it creates a mock wrapper around the process in B, as a result, it will count the times it is called.

If you have more insight or a better explanation that would be appreciated.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock

from a import A
from b import B


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(B, 'process', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test_b_call(self, mock_b):
        a = A()
        mock_b.return_value = mock_b.process
        a.process('B')
        mock_b.process.assert_called_once()
```

You can also add something like `mock_obj.process.return_value = (mock.MagicMock(), mock.MagicMock())` if you code expects something to be returned, in my actual code it expected 2 arguments.